# Pedals not turning

Tags: pedals, new-bicycle-assembly

So Christmas day and it seems the new bikes I bought the kids aren't quite going to plan! On my daughters 6 speed Viking Belgravia the pedals are not turning and the chain keeps coming off and on my sons Royal Baby Freestyle the rear hub brake is constantly rubbing but when I press the brake it does not come on.

Help!

[image: From https://www.amazon.co.uk/Viking-Belgravia-Speed-Wheel-Bike/dp/B00K82O7EA]
From https://www.amazon.co.uk/Viking-Belgravia-Speed-Wheel-Bike/dp/B00K82O7EA

[image: From https://www.amazon.com/RoyalBaby-Freestyle-12-14-16-18-20-wheels-available/dp/B07D4ZT13Y]
from [https://www.amazon.com/RoyalBaby-Freestyle-12-14-16-18-20-wheels-available/dp/B07D4ZT13Y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07D4ZT13Y)

Comment: Welcome to the Bicycle StackExchange and Merry Christmas! If the bikes are new as you wrote, you should return them back to the point of sale for the discovered defects to be corrected, or working replacements to be provided at no cost. And I would recommend reconsidering gifting your kids bicycles of such suspiciously low quality: if the things are not usable from the start, chances are they would soon require service even if fixed now . Your kids life's first cycling experience deserves better.

Comment: Did you assemble them ?  Do you still have the instructions?

Comment: I've added some photos based on googling the model/brand names you gave.  If they're not right, feel free to use the Revert function, or point out the differences.

Comment: It sounds as if you ordered the bikes online and do not know how to properly assemble them.  You need to find a buddy who is more bike-savy or take the bikes to a bike shop.

Answer (score 8):

Being somewhat general, here's some common causes for each problem you've given

**Chain comes off** - because its too slack.  Try loosening the rear wheel nuts and slide the whole wheel backward a bit.  The chain has to have some slack, but not enough to let it fall off either side.

**Pedals are not turning** - The pedal cage (bit the foot presses against) should rotate around the pedal axle reasonably freely.  It may or may not coast if spun, but it should turn around smoothly.  If not, the pedals may be faulty.

OR you might have meant:  **Crank is not turning on the bottom bracket** - this would be bad - a new bike would have the crank installed in the box.  You shouldn't have to fit a crank to a frame yourself.   If that's not turning freely, something's really wrong.

**Rear hub brake rubs** Are you sure the wheel is centered in the frame?  Its possible the tyre is rubbing on the chainstay or seatstay.  Loosen the wheel nut on one side and push/hold the rim to a central position between the stays, and retighten.   
I see that this bike has a center-mounted drink bottle cage over the rear wheel.  Check its not rubbing on the tyre either.  Finally check the training wheels haven't pressed some part of the chain cover into the wheel hub.

**Rear hub brake doesn't come on when pressed**  The coaster brake should never need servicing, and would absolutely come pre-assembled.  Sounds like the bike might have some problems.   Given its a $109 USD BSO, it might be better to return it right now under your local consumer rights.

Comment: Sorry only just realised the Chain Comes Off was for the bigger derailleur bike not the small single speed.   This may mean there's just too much chain for the gears chosen, or it could mean the rear derailleur is somehow messed up.

Answer (score 2):

If you buy a bike from a bike shop (rather than online) then they typically have to spend time setting them up before putting them on sale.

I suggest finding a bike repair shop and getting them put in order there.